# Magento Display stock per Website/Store view using advanced inventory

Tags: php, magento, inventory-management

I have 2 website under 1 magento instal (wholesale and retail)

retail url : retail.domain

wholesale url: wholesale.domain

in the wholesale website Iam using a quickorder extension where customers can view the whole catalog and add to cart in one page. 
this extension display ( name, url, quantity available and price see [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaFVP.png))

we have decided to use Woymind advanced inventory extension to separate the stock count per website (wholesale and retail) and it works just fine

**The issue**

the quickorder extension use this line of code to display the stock count;

```
<?= (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?>
```

However the above line display the global stock count.

According to Wyomind FAQ this is the code to use to display products

```
getLayout()->createBlock('advancedinventory/stocks')->output($_product); ?>
```

However when first line is changed with the second line display unecessary information all I need is to retrieve is the stock count integer per website.[see link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsDS8.png)

The quick order extension was modified to display only simple products

any help will be much appreciated

Many thanks,